# Safe get value from chain without NPE

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Does anyone know any solution to safely get value without NPE and without a lot of `if` statements?
For example, we have: `userInfo.getAddressInfo().getCityName()`,
how to get `cityName` without null-checks?

Sometimes, for my pet projects I use something like that:

```
public static <T> String safeGetValue(Supplier<String> supplier) {
    try {
        return supplier.get();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Maybe exists better way to do this.

Full example:

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class ExampleClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInfoResponse userInfo = new UserInfoResponse();

        String value = safeGetValue(() -> userInfo.getAddressInfo().getCityName());
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public static <T> String safeGetValue(Supplier<String> supplier) {
        try {
            return supplier.get();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static <T> String safeGetValue(Supplier<String> supplier, String defaultValue) {
        try {
            return supplier.get();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public static <T> String safeGetValue(Supplier<String> supplier, Runnable runnable) {
        try {
            return supplier.get();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            runnable.run();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static <T> String safeGetValue(Supplier<String> supplier, Runnable runnable, String defaultValue) {
        try {
            return supplier.get();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            runnable.run();
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

class UserInfoResponse {

    private String firstName;

    private UserAddressInfo addressInfo;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public UserAddressInfo getAddressInfo() {
        return addressInfo;
    }

    public void setAddressInfo(UserAddressInfo addressInfo) {
        this.addressInfo = addressInfo;
    }
}

class UserAddressInfo {

    private String cityName;

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a single if, or a ternary statement: String cityName = userInfo.getAddressInfo() == null ? null : userInfo.getAddressInfo().getCityName()

Comment: I'm looking for a solution without if statements.
Ternary statement can't be a good solution too because of the chain may be longer,
like: userInfo.getAddressInfo().getCityInfo().getName().toUpperCase()

Answer (score 3):

> I'm looking for a solution without if statements.
>
> Ternary statement can't be a good solution too.

Unfortunately, `if` tests and conditional expressions are the only alternatives to catching NPEs.  (But they are better alternatives!)

---

To me, the real problem is that the nulls are there in the first place.  A better idea is to modify the design so that nulls are not returned.  If they are not returned by getters, then you don't have to deal with them.

Here are some ways to design your APIs to not return `null`.

- Make it impossible to create domain objects with `null` field values:

  - Constructors and setters should check that their arguments are not null, and thrown an exception (e.g. NPE) when called with bogus `null` arguments.
  - Fields could be default initialized with non-null values.
- Have the getters return non-null values when field values are `null`.  (But see below!)
- Have the getters throw an exception when the user gets a field which should not be `null` has a `null` value.
- Use the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern).  Create an special instance of each of your domain objects that represents "no object".  Ideally, a Null Object should be immutable ... or should throw an exception if you attempt to modify it by accident.
- Use `Optional<ReferenceType>`.
- For builtin types / common types:

  - use `""` instead of `null` for strings
  - use a zero length array instead of `null` for arrays
  - use (immutable) empty collection objects instead of `null` for collection types
  - avoid the primitive wrapper types: use the primitive types that cannot be `null`.

---

The other way to look at this is that if your API is  specified so that a getter *shouldn't* return a `null`, then if it does return a `null` **that is a bug**.  So, if you then write code to turn the nulls into something else (e.g. empty strings) to avoid the pesky NPEs, what you *actually* doing is **hiding the bugs**.  A better idea is to let the NPE happen, log it, and then crash the application.  (Or return a "500 Internal Error" response.)

Fixing a bug is better than hiding a bug.

But (I hear you ask) *"What about reliability?  It is embarrassing if my code crashes with NPEs!"*

Well yes, but an NPE is better than a `null` workaround that gives incorrect answers to your users ... or writes bad data into your database.

And the conventional way to avoid bugs (e.g. NPEs) showing up in production is extensive automated testing.  More / better unit tests.  More / better system tests.  Beta test releases, pre-production servers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Optional<T>` chain you can write following

```java
UserInfoResponse userInfo = new UserInfoResponse();

String value = Optional.ofNullable(userInfo.getAddressInfo())
        .map(UserAddressInfo::getCityName)
        .orElse(null);
```

or

```java
String value = Optional.ofNullable(userInfo)
        .map(UserInfoResponse::getAddressInfo)
        .map(UserAddressInfo::getCityName)
        .orElse(null);
```

or

```java
String value = Optional.ofNullable(userInfo)
        .map(ui -> ui.getAddressInfo())
        .map(uai -> uai.getCityName())
        .orElse(null);
```